# How to clear HttpPostedFileBase with jquery if image isn't valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to set my file input element to null if the file isn't a jpg, jpeg, etc., But when I set the value of the element that holds HttpPostedFileBase to null it re triggers the change event and creates errors. is there any way to get around this?

I thought I could check at the beginning of the change event to see if the value is null but it doesn't work.

here is my html element (there are two because I'm hiding the upload text box and just displaying it as a button)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StudentImageFileBase, new { @type = "file", id = "selectedFile", style = "display: none;" })
<input type="button" value="Browse For Image" class="btn" id="pictureupload"/>
```

here is my javascript that checks the image type.

```
$(function () {
console.log("ready!");
alert("picture input function entered");

$("#pictureupload").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();
});

$("#selectedFile").change(function() {
    //this doesn't work 
    var imgVal = $('selectedFile').val();
    if (imgVal == '')
        return false;

    //check whether browser fully supports all File API
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        //get the file size and file type from file input field
        var fsize = $('#selectedFile')[0].files[0].size;
        var ftype = $('#selectedFile')[0].files[0].type;
        var fname = $('#selectedFile')[0].files[0].name;

        switch (ftype) {
            case 'image/png':
            case 'image/gif':
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                alert("Acceptable image file!");

                break;
            default:
                alert('Unsupported File!');
                $('#selectedFile').val(null); //here is where the onchange gets triggered again and 
                return false;
        }

        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("selectedFile").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };

    } else {
        alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out!
I added the line below if the file is not a jpg/gif/etc

```
        default:
            alert('Unsupported File!');
            $("#selectedFile").replaceWith($("#selectedFile").clone(true));
            return false;
```

And it clears the httppostedfilebase memeber, so when I do a post back to my server the value is null. Maybe this isn't a good solution but it's all I have found so far. Just clearing out the element by setting its value re-triggers the change event which is what I am trying to avoid. Unless there is some simple logic I could put into the change event that would combat against it?